# Regex - Select text between two string in some line

Tags: regex

I have some text like:

```
#: apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py:206
msgid ""
"Universal Product Code (UPC) is an identifier for a product which is not "
"specific to a particular  supplier. Eg an ISBN for a book."
msgstr ""

#: apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py:213
#: templates/oscar/dashboard/catalogue/product_list.html:87
#: templates/oscar/dashboard/catalogue/product_update.html:168
#: templates/oscar/dashboard/catalogue/product_update.html:190
msgid "Parent"
msgstr "والد"

#: apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py:214
msgid ""
"Only choose a parent product if this is a 'variant' of a canonical "
"catalogue.  For example if this is a size 4 of a particular t-shirt.  Leave "
"blank if this is a CANONICAL PRODUCT (ie there is only one version of this "
"product)."
msgstr ""
```

I want to select text between `msgid ""` and `msgstr ""` with regex. I don't want to select translated `msgid`.

How I can do this?

Comment: What did you try? In what language/tool you are doing this?

Comment: Did you try anything? `aaa.*?bbb` with `s` modifier should work *probably* work. [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/kW3zR1/7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You do that like this:</strike>

```
(?s)aaa(.*?)bbb
```

That is, use the `s` option or its equivalent in your language in order to allow `.` to match newlines.

---

If `aaa` and `bbb` must be on their own lines, you can do:

```
(?sm)^aaa$(.*?)^bbb$
```

The `m` option enables `^` and `$` to match at each start/end of line.

Here's that last case on regex101: http://regex101.com/r/oM7fQ2/1

---

**UPDATE** Now the question is substantially different...

```
(?sm)^msgid\s+"(.*?)"\s*\n(.*?)^msgstr\s+"(.*?)"\s*$
```

This also captures the strings between quotes.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/oM7fQ2/3

Comment: thanks. works but with some mistake that is my wrong question. I will update my question and please update your answer.

Comment: Yeah you've oversimplified your question... I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select text between `aaa` and `bbb` with regex.

This might help you. Get the matched group from index 1.

```
^a{3}\r?\n([\s\S]*?)\r?\n(?=^b{3}\r?\n?)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/mH1aV2/6)

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  a{3}                     'a' (3 times)
  \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional)
  \n                       '\n' (newline)     
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [\s\S]*?                 any character (0 or more times)(least possible)
  )                        end of \1      
  \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional)
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    ^                        the beginning of the string
    b{3}                     'b' (3 times)
    \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional)
    \n?                      '\n' (newline) (optional)
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

---

#### EDIT

> I want to select text between `msgid ""` and `msgstr ""` with regex.

As per your edit change it as per below regex:

```
^msgid ""\r?\n([\s\S]*?)\r?\n(?=^msgstr ""\r?\n?)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/mH1aV2/7)